# Two XML documents xpath xslt mapping

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Been trying for hours getting this to work but I must be missing something.

I want to map two XML documents together by an id in both documents.
I can get data output from both documents using one XSLT but I don't know how to map them.

first xml:

```
...
<member>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>John</name>
</member>
<member>
  <id>2</id>
  <name>Otto</name>
</member>
...
```

second xml: (ss namespace)

```
...
<row>
  <cell ss:Type="String">id</cell>
  <cell ss:Type="String">Number 1</cell>
  <cell ss:Type="String">Number 2</cell>
</row>
<row>
  <cell ss:Type="Number">1</cell>
  <cell ss:Type="Number">1231312313</cell>
  <cell ss:Type="Number">234234234342</cell>
</row>
<row>
  <cell ss:Type="Number">2</cell>
  <cell ss:Type="Number">4353453453</cell>
  <cell ss:Type="Number">345345345455</cell>
</row>
...
```

I loop through name and id elements in the XSLT file and inside this loop I'm trying to get the value to map to the id in the second xml using apply templates.

The final HTML output should look something like:

```
Id      Name          Number 1         Number 2
1       John          1231312313       234234234342
2       Otto          4353453453       345345345455
```

Comment: Are you only limited to xslt?

Comment: yes, only xslt to produce a merged list of html output.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the XML you are expecting to be output in this case? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC I've updated the question with the output.

Comment: Do you use an XSLT 2.0 or 1.0 processor? With an XSLT 2.0 processor supporting XSLT 2.0's `key` function with a third argument cross-references to another document are easier to code than with XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @MartinHonnen 1.0, and I must use 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with call-template "function" and passed the value for id as parameter. Then pick up the "Number" tags values in the second file with a for-each and a if-statement. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following can be a starting point:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0" xmlns:ss="NS:SS">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </table>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ss:row">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ss:cell">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ss:cell[1]">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="string()"/>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="$id"/></td>
    <!-- Especially for large amounts of data, making use of key() would be better than "//" 
         The key() call can be wrapped inside a <xsl:for-each select="document('firstDocument.xml')>
         that changes the context to the other document -->
    <td><xsl:value-of select="document('firstDocument.xml')//member[id=$id]/name"/></td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This has to be applied to what you call the second document. The first document is called using the `document()` function.

As Martin Honnen points out, using `key()` would be better (especially if you have large data sets). See the comment about wrapping a call to `key()` into `<xsl:for-each>` to make this work in XSLT 1.0.